# Extract element from array

Tags: php, opencart

I know i can extract the value of price using
`echo $prod_option[0]['product_option_value'][0]['price'];`

How can i extract all the [price] values from my array if i don't know how many arrays the product_option_value has ?

EDIT: Seems i didn't explain what i am trying to do very well.
What i need to do is extract all products from an Opencart website and if the product has options create each option as it's own product in the csv
This is my function

```
    public function index()
    {
        /*header("Content-Type: text/csv"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=faceboook-feed.csv");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");   
        print "title,description,google_product_category,link,image_link,availability,price,brand,condition".PHP_EOL;*/
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();



        
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            $price=($product['special'] ? $product['special'] :$product['price']);
            $prod_option = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($product['product_id']);
            
        
            
            if(!empty($prod_option)){
                foreach($prod_option as $innerArray)
                {
                    if(is_array($innerArray)){
                        foreach($innerArray as $innerArray2) {
                            if(is_array($innerArray2)){
                                foreach($innerArray2 as $innerArray3){
                                    $csv_line.='"'.$this->clean($product['name']).$innerArray3['name'].'",';
                                    $csv_line.='"'.$this->clean($product['description']).'",';
                                    $csv_line.='"Hardware > Building Materials > Flooring & Carpet",';
                                    $csv_line.='"'.str_ireplace("&amp;","&",$this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id='.$product['product_id'])).'",';
                                    $csv_line.='"'.trim(HTTP_SERVER,"/")."/image/".$product['image'].'",';
                                    $csv_line.='"'.($product['status']==1 ? 'in stock':'out of stock').'",';
                                    $tmpPrice = round($this->tax->calculate($price,$product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')),2);
                                    if($innerArray3['price_prefix'] == "-")
                                    {
                                        $tmpPrice = $tmpPrice - $innerArray3['price'];
                                    }
                                    else if($innerArray3['price_prefix'] == "+")
                                    {
                                        $tmpPrice = $tmpPrice + $innerArray3['price'];
                                    }
                                    $csv_line.='"'.$tmpPrice.'",';
                                    $csv_line.='"'.(empty($product['manufacturer']) ? $product['name'] : $product['manufacturer']).'",';
                                    $csv_line.='"new"';
                                    print $csv_line.PHP_EOL;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $csv_line.='"'.$this->clean($product['name']).'",';
                $csv_line.='"'.$this->clean($product['description']).'",';
                $csv_line.='"Hardware > Building Materials > Flooring & Carpet",';
                $csv_line.='"'.str_ireplace("&amp;","&",$this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id='.$product['product_id'])).'",';
                $csv_line.='"'.trim(HTTP_SERVER,"/")."/image/".$product['image'].'",';
                $csv_line.='"'.($product['status']==1 ? 'in stock':'out of stock').'",';
                $csv_line.='"'.round($this->tax->calculate($price,$product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')),2).' '.$this->session->data['currency'].'",';
                $csv_line.='"'.(empty($product['manufacturer']) ? $product['name'] : $product['manufacturer']).'",';
                $csv_line.='"new"';
                print $csv_line.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
```

My array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_option_id] => 226
            [product_option_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 15
                            [option_value_id] => 39
                            [name] => Red
                            [image] => 
                            [quantity] => 2
                            [subtract] => 1
                            [price] => 10.0000
                            [price_prefix] => +
                            [weight] => 0.00000000
                            [weight_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 16
                            [option_value_id] => 40
                            [name] => Blue
                            [image] => 
                            [quantity] => 5
                            [subtract] => 1
                            [price] => -10.0000
                            [price_prefix] => +
                            [weight] => 0.00000000
                            [weight_prefix] => +
                        )

                )

            [option_id] => 5
            [name] => Select
            [type] => select
            [value] => 
            [required] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it visual for yourself you can do this.

```
$prices = array(); 

foreach($prod_option[0]['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
    $prices[] = $product_option_value["price"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without a loop using `array_column()`:

```
$prices = array_column($prod_option[0]['product_option_value'], 'price');
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally I'd make a loop for collecting the prices

```
$arr = $prod_option[0]['product_option_value'];
$prices = [];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    $prices[] = $arr[i]['price'];
```